# does dgrid3d generate new values? (gnuplot 5x)

Tags: datagrid, gnuplot

my data looks like this:

```
 394    648.164 0.27 
 394    648.202 0.27 
 394    648.194 0.28 
 397    648.741 0.27 
 403    647.685 0.27 
 404    647.348 0.27
```

and goes on like this for about 500 rows ....

```
1st column values range from: 0:1200
2nd column values range from 550:900
3rd column values range from 0:1
```

I plotted a heat map with that data in gnuplot with a code like this:

```
set grid
set pm3d map
set dgrid3d 500,500 
splot 'Data_table_lvl1.csv' using 1:2:3
```

this gets me a heat map exactly the way I wanted it but the values on the `y axes` ranges from `200 to 1100` (those are the values from the 2nd column)
I read the documentation entry but I don`t really understand why this happens... guess it's a simple lack of mathematical understanding.

So my question is how does gnuplot actually calculate the grid from the data and is there a way to modify this behaviour?

Comment: Please edit your Q to indicate what is your desired grid axes (0?) Good luck.

Comment: I guess you mean `1st column values...`

Comment: yes I do sorry i wasn't thinking

Comment: Yes, gnuplot should calculate the grid based on the data's bounding box, i.e. minimum and maximum values in the given data columns. If you find, that this isn't the case you can try to figure out if gnuplot reads wrong values, by using `stats 'Data_table_lvl1.csv' using 1:2; show variables STATS` and looking for the variables `STATS_index_min_x`, `STATS_index_max_x`, `STATS_min_x` and `STATS_max_x` to see if those values agree with what you expect. (and the same with the variables `STATS_..._y`). If all is ok, but the gridded result is wrong, please upload your data file somewhere for debuggin